# Core data entity disappears when app resumes from background

Tags: ios, core-data

I have an app that uses a read-only Core Data database (meaning I never write to the database). I have a view controller that fetches some core data entities and displays them in a table. So for example, I have a core data entity named `Photo`, and in my view controller I have, say `@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *photos;`, which is a list of Photo objects.

Now everything works fine when the app launches fresh. But when I go to that view and exit the app (so it's still in the background) and reenter it, the `@property` I've set up becomes `nil`. I still see all `UITableViewCell`s currently on screen. When I attempt to scroll, though, the app crashes.

I have multiple views that use Core Data stuff, but some of them work just fine. I'm wondering why for some view controllers my Core Data object set up as a `@property` disappears when the app returns to foreground.

Thanks!

Comment: More info... like the code for your property, and what you do when your controller is unloaded and reloaded from both the app and display.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First recommendation: you should be using an `NSFetchedResultsController` rather than an array. This is much more efficient and will take care of all memory considerations for you, beside many other advantages. As a matter of fact, it was designed specifically to manage the `datasource` of a table view based on Core Data.

If you still want to use your array, I speculate that you failed to **initialize** it properly.

In your `viewDidLoad` method, do not just assign the fetched results from core data but do it with proper initialization:

```
self.photos = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:coreDataResults];
```

Now the array should persist.

Comment: Yes alloc init it seems to work. I'm not sure about `NSFetchedResultsController` though. Will it retain the `UIManagedDocument`?

Comment: It will retain it's fetched results, whatever those are.

Comment: Okay. I'll try that next time. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured out what's wrong with my code. So this is what I did to fetch the core data stuff:

```
[DatabaseHelper openDatabase:@"database" usingBlock:^(UIManagedDocument *document) {
     NSFetchRequest *request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Shop"];
     request.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ecategory = %@", self.category];
     NSError *error = nil;
     NSArray *matches = [document.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
     self.shops = matches;
     [self updateTable];
}];
```

This correctly fetches the results, but the problem is, although I think I retained the Core Data objects, they actually belong to a `UIManagedDocumentContext`, and I didn't retain that. So when the app returns to foreground, the context is gone, and the core data objects become nil.

So what I did is declare a new property: `@property (nonatomic, strong) UIManagedDocument *database;` and then set `self.database = document;` in the block. Now the controller will retain the context and everything works fine.